# Adding multiple "public functions" in JavaScript using an object

Tags: javascript, class

As everyone should know, in JavaScript there are no actual `Classes`.

However, you can use a simple function to make a class like setup.

Ex:

```
var Person = function(name){//class like function
    this.name = name;//public 

    var display = function(text){//private
        return text;
    }

    this.getDressed = function(){//public
        return display(this.name + " needs to get dressed.");
    }

};
var person = new Person("John"),
    name = person.name,//returns "John"
    dressed = person.getDressed();//returns "John needs to get dressed",
    show = person.display("Hello");//throws error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'display'" because there is no such function because it was private.
```

My "class" will have many functions and I want to know if there is a way to do something like (which I know doesn't work):

```
this = {
  fun1: function () {},
  fun2: function () {},
  fun3: function () {}
}
```

because I find this doing:

```
this.fun1 = function(){};
this.fun2 = function(){};
this.fun3 = function(){};
```

Is quite ugly. Is there a way to keep all my functions in an object and attaching then to `this`?

Comment: I think you mean this.getDressed is public, right?

Comment: Oops, yes that's what I meant. I changed that.

Comment: I found this approach very interesting: http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to access private members, you can do this:

```
function Person(){
    //stuff
}

Person.prototype = {
    fun1:function(){},
    fun2:function(){},
    //etc
};
```

You will still be able to access `this` from within the prototype functions.

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
function Person(name){
   var display = function(){//stuff};

   return {
       name: name,
       fun1: function(){},
       fun2: function(){}
   };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var funcs = {
  fun1: function () {},
  fun2: function () {},
  fun3: function () {}
}

// Simple combiner
for (var f in funcs) {
  if (funcs.hasOwnProperty(f)) {
    this[f] = funcs[f];
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the best idea. Because of the performance.

Comment: True, but it does directly answer the OPs question.

Answer (score 0):

You've essentially got the idea.

In your Person example, simply apply the right context to your `getDressed` function:

```
var that;
var Person = function(name){//class like function
    that = this; 
};
show = person.prototype.display.call(that, "Hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$.extend(Person.prototype, yourthisobject);` if you want to keep everything contained in a **this** object.